# htaccess expression for root files only excluding directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Trying to make an expression:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)
```

The problem with this expression `(.*)` is that, it applies the condition to all directories as well.

Looking for an alternative to select root files only with (.dot) extension.

Does anybody have a clue how to deal with it?

Comment: Negative Lookahead for '/' might help RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)(?!/)